# Обособление оборотов с "помимо"

Tags: пунктуация

Кто-нибудь подскажет, нужна ли здесь запятая после "то"? (Обособляя оборот "помимо тех, что уже упомянуты ранее")

Что касается сервисных центров, то помимо тех, что уже упомянуты ранее, у нас в планах открытие площадки в Нижнем Новгороде.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше запятую не ставить, так как конструкция "помимо тех, что уже упомянуты ранее, у нас в планах открытие площадки в Нижнем Новгороде" является цельной, перестановка ее частей нежелательна (местоимение "тех" должно следовать после "сервисных центров)".

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Правильно:

Что касается сервисных центров, то, помимо тех что уже упомянуты ранее, у нас в планах открытие площадки в Нижнем Новгороде.

Помимо того(,) что — союз. Синтаксические конструкции, начинающиеся с союза «помимо того что», выделяются знаками препинания (запятыми). При этом первый знак препинания может ставиться либо перед составным союзом, либо между его частями (перед словом «что»). http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/221131/Помимо

Comment: София, "помимо того что" - союз. Но разве из этого следует, что "помимо тех, что" - тоже союз?

Comment: Какая разница, принцип один и тот же: предлог + союз = составной союз. По крайней мере, такой составной союз лучше, чем скопление запятых, которые не проясняют, а затемняют смысл.

Comment: "Помимо тех, что" не союз. Скопления запятых можно избежать другим способом: помимо упомянутых ранее.

Comment: А какова грамматика предложения? "Что касается сервисных центров, то (помимо тех, что уже упомянуты ранее, у нас в планах открытие площадки в Нижнем Новгороде)". Я считаю, что коррелят ТО относится к осложненному предложению, которое начинается с обособленного предложного оборота. А у вас "ТО" к чему относится? И к чему относится этот предложный оборот?  Вот еще пример: Что касается «Курска», то (помимо первого мощного удара, на него обрушились многотонные удары винтов иностранного корабля).

Comment: Предложный оборот здесь может быть обособленным и не обособленным. К нему (как к дополнению или обстоятельству - мнения разделились) относится придаточное "что уже упомянуты ранее". Соответственно, ТО относится к осложненному или к сложному предложению.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение Софьи интересно, но все же оборот "помимо тех" - это всё равно, что "кроме тех", а, как известно, по нынешним правилам, такие члены предложения (это же дополнение) обособляются независимо от того, имеется ли смысл "включая" или "исключая" (см. Розенталя).

Comment: Но мне кажется, что обособлять не стоит просто потому, что оборот как-то не смотрится. Излишнее нагромождение. Хотя еще недавно я бы тоже встала на сторону тех, кто отстаивает постановку запятой.

Comment: Никак не припомню, чтобы в правилах было сказано, что запятая ставится или нет в зависмости от того, "смотрится" она или "не смотрится"

Comment: Но обычно ошибки коробят. И потом, Запятание пишет, что обороты с предлогом «помимо» (в значении «кроме»), выполняющие в предложении функцию дополнения, обычно выделяются знаками препинания, но могут и не выделяться. Хотя, соглашусь с вами в том, что чаще они все-таки выделяются.

Answer (score 0):

Аленка, все зависит от смысловой нагрузки, положения в предложении, порядка слов в предложении, авторского замысла и других факторов. Однако, как указано на Грамоте, "В спорных случаях окончательное решение о постановке знаков препинания принимает автор текста".

***В приведенном вами примере постановка запятой обязательна!***